# MongoDB update query to set existing field into array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have following mongo sub-document

```
"location" : {
        "zipCode" : "90670",
        "lat" : "33.942669",
        "lng" : "-118.074384",
        "city" : "Santa Fe Springs",
        "state" : "California",
        "streetAddress" : "12131 Telegraph Road, 2nd Floor",
    }
```

Can someone suggest me mongo update query or node function to get the following document

```
"location" : {
        "zipCode" : "90670",
        "city" : "Santa Fe Springs",
        "state" : "California",
        "streetAddress" : "12131 Telegraph Road, 2nd Floor",
        "geo" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 33.942669 ,-118.074384 ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the node.js mongodb driver you can do something like:

```
var firstQuery = {


"zipCode" : "90670",
   "city" : "Santa Fe Springs",
   "state" : "California",
   "streetAddress" : "12131 Telegraph Road, 2nd Floor"
};

db.collection('yourCollection').find(firstQuery).toArray(function(err, results) {
    if (err) return err;
    results.forEach(function(record) {
        var geo = {
            "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ record.lat ,record.lng ]
        };

        var newRecord  = {
            zipCode: record.zipCode,
            city: record.city,
            state: record.state,
            streetAddress: record.streetAddres,
            geo: geo
        };

        db.collection('yourCollection').update(record, newRecord, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                //do whatever you want with this
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Even you can do something like  db.collection.update({x:1}, {$unset: {x:'',y:''}, $set: {point: {x:1, y:2}}}) from the client.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
var query = {
   "zipCode" : "90670",
   "city" : "Santa Fe Springs",
   "state" : "California",
   "streetAddress" : "12131 Telegraph Road, 2nd Floor"
};

var operator = {
   $unset: {
    "lat" : "",
    "lng" : ""
   },
   $set: {
      "geo" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 33.942669 ,-118.074384 ]
      }
   }       
};

var options = {
  multi: true
}

db.yourCollection.update(query, operator, options);
```

This will affect all your records that match with the query indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This change cannot be done in a single operation. You will need to first get the document that you need to change and then update the document with the new format.